# ASCII command send to bluetooth device for receive data using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, pybluez

I want to send hex cmd (0X2A,0X0A,0X58)from raspberry pi to my another bluetooth interfaced device(Arduino) for receive sensor data.when I am using server.send(0X2A,0X0A,0X58).its not working .So how to send that request cmd for receive data from bluetooth.I have already paired my Bluetooth devices .

```
from bluetooth import 

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ],
#                   protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ]
                    )

print "Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ", client_info

try:
    while True:
        server.send(0X2A,0X0A,0X58)
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print "received [%s]" % data
except IOError:
    pass

print "disconnected"
client_sock.close()
```

Comment: Did you mean to miss off the thing you are importing on line 1?

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You may change send serial data as,

1. `server.send('\x2A\x0A\x58')` or
2. `server.send('2A0A58'.decode("hex"))`